# For what values of a does the vector space have zero, none or infinite elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I'm kind of confused on how to interpret this vector space, is it the vector space for which the x, y, z components are multiplied by the given matrix? If so what does the matrix after the = mean?

It's really confusing to me how I'm supposed to solve this for an a. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would apprecatie it.

Comment: For each particular value of $a$ this is a set of linear equations. Count the number of solutions to see how that depends on $a$. You could work out $a=0$ and $a=1$ to get an idea of what to do in the general case.

Comment: This is [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Specifying_the_domain).  It is the set of all points where the equation at the end is true.  If you expand the matrix multiply you will get three equations in $a,x,y,z$.  For a given $a$ the equations are linear and will define a subspace.  You are to find which values of $a$ give what kind of a subspace.

Comment: Do you know the criterion when $Ax=b$ has no , one or infinite many solutions considering the rank of $A$ and of $A$ concanatted with $b$ ? The solutions only form a (nonempty) vectorspace if the zero vector is a solution, that is $b=0$. In this case, if $n\times n$ is the size of $A$, there are nontrivial solutions ($x\ne 0$) if and only if $rank(A)<n$ and in this case there are infinite many solutions.

Comment: @RossMillikan No, $V_a$ is clearly not a subspace unless $a=0$.

Comment: @Peter thank you a lot, that explains it!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I understand that for a = 0 the equation is linearly dependent, is that the reason that V is only a subspace when this is the case?

Comment: A vector space (including a subspace) must include a $0$ element. But $A0 = 0$, so the solutions to $Ax = b$ can only include $x = 0$ when $b = 0$. In your case, $$b = \begin{pmatrix}a(a+2)\\a^2(a+2)\\a^3(a+2)\end{pmatrix}$$ which is only $0$ when $a = 0$ or $a = -2$ (David C. Ullrich overlooked the latter possibility).